# Migrating custom dynamic partitioner from Flink 1.7 to Flink 1.9

Tags: apache-flink

I am trying to migrate a custom dynamic partitioner from Flink 1.7 to Flink 1.9. The original partitioner implemented the `selectChannels` method within the `StreamPartitioner` interface like this:

```java
    // Original: working for Flink 1.7
    //@Override
    public int[] selectChannels(SerializationDelegate<StreamRecord<T>> streamRecordSerializationDelegate,
                                int numberOfOutputChannels) {
        T value = streamRecordSerializationDelegate.getInstance().getValue();
        if (value.f0.isBroadCastPartitioning()) {
            // send to all channels
            int[] channels = new int[numberOfOutputChannels];
            for (int i = 0; i < numberOfOutputChannels; ++i) {
                channels[i] = i;
            }
            return channels;
        } else if (value.f0.getPartitionKey() == -1) {
            // random partition
            returnChannels[0] = random.nextInt(numberOfOutputChannels);
        } else {
            returnChannels[0] = partitioner.partition(value.f0.getPartitionKey(), numberOfOutputChannels);
        }
        return returnChannels;
    }
```

I am not sure how to migrate this to Flink 1.9, since the `StreamPartitioner` interface has changed as illustrated below:

```java
    // New: required by Flink 1.9
    @Override
    public int selectChannel(SerializationDelegate<StreamRecord<T>> streamRecordSerializationDelegate) {
        T value = streamRecordSerializationDelegate.getInstance().getValue();
        if (value.f0.isBroadCastPartitioning()) {
            /* 
            It is illegal to call this method for broadcast channel selectors and this method can remain not 
            implemented in that case (for example by throwing UnsupportedOperationException).
            */
        } else if (value.f0.getPartitionKey() == -1) {
            // random partition
            returnChannels[0] = random.nextInt(numberOfChannels);
        } else {
            returnChannels[0] = partitioner.partition(value.f0.getPartitionKey(), numberOfChannels);
        }
        //return returnChannels;
        return returnChannels[0];
    }
```

Note that `selectChannels` has been replaced with `selectChannel`. So, it is no longer possible to return multiple output channels as originally done above for the case of broadcasted elements. As a matter of fact, `selectChannel` should not be invoked for this particular case. Any thoughts on how to tackle this?

Answer (score 1):

With Flink 1.9, you cannot dynamically broadcast to all channels anymore. Your `StreamPartitioner` has to statically specify if it's a broadcast with `isBroadcast`. Then, `selectChannel` is never invoked.

Do you have a specific use case, where you'd need to dynamically switch?